# Ensure that library has been initialized

Tags: c++, libraries, initialization

I am using a 3rd party library that must be initialized with `Lib::init()` before any of its other functions may be called and that must be uninitialized with `Lib::destroy()` before the application ends. My classes that use the library just assume that it is initialized. This is not a problem in my application - I am calling `init()` immediately when entering `main` and I am calling `destroy()` directly before leaving it.

Unfortunately, in my unit tests, I sometimes forget to initialize the library. This made me thinking: *If I forget to call `Lib::init()`, other users of my classes will also forget to call it.* To tackle this problem, I added a RAII wrapper that calls `Lib::init()` in the constructor and `Lib::destroy()` in the destructor:

```
struct LibInstance
{
    LibInstance()
    {
        Lib::init();
    }
    LibInstance(LibInstance const&) = delete;
    LibInstance(LibInstance&&) = delete;
    LibInstance& operator=(LibInstance const&) = delete;
    LibInstance& operator=(LibInstance&&) = delete;
    ~LibInstance()
    {
        Lib::destroy();
    }
};
```

Now all of my classes that use the library require a `LibInstance const&` argument in the constructor or in the respective member function. This way, it is guaranteed that `init()` has been called before:

```
struct MyClass
{
    int do_something_with_lib(LibInstance const& /*instance*/)
    {
        // Here, we can be sure that Lib::init() has been called,
        // because the user was able to pass a LibInstance argument.
        Lib::foo();
        return Lib::bar();
    }
};
```

At first, this wrapper seemed like a really good solution and I was happy about it. It is impossible to use my class without initializing the library. However, after some time, I find it really strange that many of my classes now require a `LibInstance` argument and never access it. Additionally, it is sometimes inconvenient to pass the `LibInstance` from `main` down to the place where it is actually used.

Is it a good idea that my classes take an additional (unused) argument just for ensuring that `Lib::init()` has been called?

If it is not a good idea, what is a better way to ensure the initialization?

Comment: Does `Lib` have a way to see if `init` has been called?  Is there any of your classes that is always used, or first used?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `Lib::is_initialized()` (or something comparable). Of course, I could wrap the function and set a global `bool lib_is_initialized`, but I want to avoid globals if possible. Regarding your second question: In my main application, there are classes that are always used (e.g., `Engine` with a main loop). However, these classes are (currently) not necessary in the unit tests and most components can be tested on their own.

Comment: I really like that the additional `LibInstance` argument makes it nearly impossible to forget the initialization. I can also live with the fact that this requires passing the instance to all necessary places. However, it feels like I am implementing some kind of anti pattern, even though I can say exactly why I feel that way.

Comment: Is it feasible to let `LibInstance` be a wrapper for the whole library, rather than just the `init`/`destroy` calls? That way, you wouldn't have unused arguments, because the argument would be used to reach the library functions.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Do you mean that I wrap all library calls and then use `LibInstance::foo()` instead of `Lib::foo()`? That would give more meaning to the `LibInstance` arguments. It is probably not feasible for large libraries, but it might work in my case.

Comment: @pschill, that is indeed what I meant.